# How can I update an iOS device using iTunes on Mac without backing it up?

Tags: macos, itunes, backup, software-update

Since Apple's weird rule makes me unable to upgrade my phone via mobile data. I have to use iTunes to upgrade.

I have a lot of traffic so it's not a big deal for me.

I have a Mac with me and I can connect my phone to the Mac. And I have downloaded the latest iOS on my Mac.

But before updating, it says "backing up ..." and it seems to take forever to finish.

So is it possible to update my iOS WITHOUT backing up it first?

- My current iOS: `12.1.2`
- My Mac: `10.14.2 (18C54)`
- The downloaded iOS version: `12.1.3`

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can update your device using Mobile Data by creating a WiFi Hotspot, while your data is on and update your device using the WiFi Hotspot.

Try this:

> Quit iTunes.
>
> Open a Terminal (Applications >  Utilities > Terminal)
>
> Type or copy the following  `command:defaults write  com.apple.iTunes 
>   AutomaticDeviceBackupsDisabled - bool true`
>
> Open iTunes.
>
> Connect the iPhone.
>
> Make Sync without backing up.

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7640010?answerId=32668610022#32668610022

Comment: What's sad that I am using iPhone-USB as the network connection of my Mac....