# How can I update an iOS device using Finder without backing it up?

Tags: macos, finder, backup, software-update

As of macOS Catalina, updating iOS devices is now done using Finder rather than iTunes. Thus, [the solution proposed here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/350710/154794) which uses the command `defaults write com.apple.iTunes AutomaticDeviceBackupsDisabled -bool true` no longer works.

How can I disable automatic backups when updating an iOS device from Finder (as opposed to iTunes)?

Answer (score 4):

The defaults key still exists. However, the iPhone-related functionality in iTunes was extracted in macOS Catalina, the domain was changed.

The following command is now required:

```sh
defaults write com.apple.AMPDevicesAgent AutomaticDeviceBackupsDisabled -bool true
```

Comment: idk why you wouldn't want the backup, but +1 for the research ;)

Comment: No prob. Personally I use the one I have in my hand rather than one a million virtual miles away, in case I need a fast recovery. I just don't trust OTA for much if I can have it locally.

Comment: This is needed for me. I have an ipad with around 600gb of images. Backups takes several hours and by the time it completes I believe the passcode entered at the beginning is no longer valid and the update fails. I use this after my backup is complete to avoid failing another update. Thanks for the new command!

Comment: It worked... Thank you!!

Comment: There are reason why you do not want backup - it would replace the old one, and sometimes you need to have this old one when you use different iphone as replacement.