# How can I update an iOS device on Monterey using Finder without backing it up?

Tags: ios, finder, monterey

On macOS Monterey, iOS devices are updated using Finder.

How do I disable automatic backup while updating an iOS device?  The software is first downloaded (about 5.5G), a backup is attempted, and the whole thing is aborted if the backup fails (for e.g. if there isn't enough space on your laptop).

NB: The [solution proposed here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421180/how-can-i-update-an-ios-device-using-finder-without-backing-it-up) for Catalina no longer works.